# Looking for better algorithm for match 3 gem collision detection

Tags: algorithm

im building simple match 3 game for learning propose , now i have section in the simple game 
when the Gem moved to some direction ( X or Y ) and need to find out if the gems around are
the same and more then 1 in a row i programmed not so smart solution  and im looking for ideas to make it more general. 
this is my code with comments :

/

```
* 
 detect and store the gems that are alike the selected gem
*/

bool GameController::matchDetector(Gem* pSelected)
{
    // get the gem that are near the selected gem based on the selected gem movement type 
    // for example if moved right the movement type is (RightMovment) so the next gem is row,col+1
    Gem* pNextSprite = getNextGem(pSelected,pSelected->getGemState());
    // array that will store the Gems that are found for each direction array of its own
    CCArray * rightGemsToRemove = CCArray::create();
    CCArray * leftGemsToRemove = CCArray::create();
    CCArray * upperGemsToRemove = CCArray::create();
    CCArray * downGemsToRemove = CCArray::create();

    if(pNextSprite == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //copy the selected NEXT gem to the selected gem
    //so the calculation to find the next gems will be right 
    pSelected->swap(pNextSprite);
    int col = pSelected->getColNum();
    int row = pSelected->getRowNum();
    /*

        its long switch case that on its option doing the same so only the first one commented 

    */
    switch(pSelected->getGemState())
    {
        case kMoveRight:
        {
            // if its right direction i need to run on all the right gems until its NOT the same and stor it 
            for(int i=pSelected->getColNum()+1;i < maxGemsInCol;i++)
            {
                std::string nextInnerSpriteId = pUT->setGemId(i,row);
                // get the next gem from the container 
                Gem* pNextInnerSprite = (Gem*)GameSingleTone::getInstance()->getGemsDictionary()->objectForKey(nextInnerSpriteId);

                if(pNextInnerSprite == NULL)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // add it to the container 
                    rightGemsToRemove->addObject(pNextInnerSprite);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case kMoveLeft:
        {

            for(int i=pSelected->getColNum()-1;i < maxGemsInCol;i++)
            {
                std::string nextInnerSpriteId = pUT->setGemId(i,row);
                Gem* pNextInnerSprite = (Gem*)GameSingleTone::getInstance()->getGemsDictionary()->objectForKey(nextInnerSpriteId);

                if(pNextInnerSprite == NULL)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    leftGemsToRemove->addObject(pNextInnerSprite);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case kMoveUp:
        {
            for(int i=pSelected->getRowNum()+1;i < maxGemsInRow ;i++)
            {
                std::string nextInnerSpriteId = pUT->setGemId(col,i);
                Gem* pNextInnerSprite = (Gem*)GameSingleTone::getInstance()->getGemsDictionary()->objectForKey(nextInnerSpriteId);

                if(pNextInnerSprite == NULL)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    upperGemsToRemove->addObject(pNextInnerSprite);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case kMoveDown:
        {
            for(int i=pSelected->getRowNum()-1;i < maxGemsInRow ;i++)
            {
                std::string nextInnerSpriteId = pUT->setGemId(col,i);
                Gem* pNextInnerSprite = (Gem*)GameSingleTone::getInstance()->getGemsDictionary()->objectForKey(nextInnerSpriteId);

                if(pNextInnerSprite == NULL)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    downGemsToRemove->addObject(pNextInnerSprite);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    /*
    this function will run on all the arrays and will check which gems needs to be removed from the GRID and all the rest ( fill the grid with new gems and so on .. ) 
    */
    handleGems(downGemsToRemove,upperGemsToRemove,leftGemsToRemove,rightGemsToRemove)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's absolutely nothing wrong with the algorithm you're currently using ("loop through the gems in the given direction till you hit one that's different").  Unless the game board has millions of rows or columns, this will take a few microseconds at most, and it's by far the most straightforward algorithm you could use.

One thing I don't understand is why you accumulate four separate lists `rightGemsToRemove`, `leftGemsToRemove` etc.  Will `handleGems()` do something different with each kind?  If not, just use a single `gemsToRemove` list.

Another suggestion: you have four cases that each contain basically identical code.  This kind of repetition is fertile ground for bugs to develop: if you need to make some change to the logic, it's easy to forget to make the same change in all four copies, or to accidentally make the wrong change (using e.g. copy and paste).  I suggest reducing your `switch` statement down to:

```
int dx, dy;
switch (switch(pSelected->getGemState())) {
case kMoveRight: dx = 1;  dy = 0;  break;
case kMoveLeft:  dx = -1; dy = 0;  break;
case kMoveUp:    dx = 0;  dy = -1; break;
case kMoveDown:  dx = 0;  dy = 1;  break;
}
```

After that you can write just a single loop that adds `dx` to `x` and `dy` to `y`:

```
int x = pSelected->getColNum() + dx;
int y = pSelected->getRowNum() + dy;
while (x >= 0 && x < maxGemsInRow && y >= 0 && x < maxGemsInCol) {
    std::string nextInnerSpriteId = pUT->setGemId(x, y);
    Gem* pNextInnerSprite = (Gem*)GameSingleTone::getInstance()->getGemsDictionary()->objectForKey(nextInnerSpriteId);

    if(pNextInnerSprite == NULL) {
        return false;
    } else {
        gemsToRemove->addObject(pNextInnerSprite);
    }

    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}
```

Arguably even better: if `kMoveRight` etc. are all small integer values, you can just look them up directly from a static array:

```
static int dxFromMovement[] = { 1, -1, 0, 0 };
static int dyFromMovement[] = { 0, 0, -1, 1 };

dx = dxFromMovement[pSelected->getGemState()];
dy = dyFromMovement[pSelected->getGemState()];
```

This might be slightly faster, though in my opinion it's slightly less clear, and the speed differences are so far below noticeable that it's not worth it in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer !